# Homepage doesn't redirect from HTTP to the HTTPS same page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here's my website structure :

```
/public_html
     /subdir
         /wordpress website
```

My main domain was on public_html and I move the whole to the subdir with this htacess in the root (public_html) (from [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

When I access to example.com or www.example.com (without https), it redirects to : `https://example.com/subdir`

When I access to example.com/page1, it redirects well to `https://example.com/page1`

It's a bit annoying. How can I resolve this please ?

Thanks

Comment: What does WordPress have as the home_url and site_url in it's settings? Also you might just have that cached, try a different browser or your phone to see if you get the same result.

Comment: Hi, yes I changed the home_url and site_url in settings (it would not work on another page else). It's not a cache issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's ok

This was due to the SSL redirect code in the public_html/subdir/.htaccess files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I moved this code to public_html/.htaccess and the site is now working as expected.